# How to remove file from /system/xbin Android

Tags: android, system, adb

I had copy tcpdump to /system/xbin on my device.

How can I remove It? when I try :

`adb shell rm /system/xbin`

I get:

`rm failed for /system/xbin/tcpdump, Read-only file system`

Comment: you need to mount /system to mode RW. After that, you can use rm command

Answer (score 1):

I had to do

`adb root`

`adb remount`

then rm is possible

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell rm /system/xbin/tcpdump
```

or

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
adb shell rm /system/xbin/tcpdump
```

Comment: I am getting this error when i used the second approach. mount: '/dev/block/platform/soc.0/f9824900.sdhci/by-name/system'->'/system': Device or resource busy